# Need help with layout (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, resize

[alt text http://img705.yfrog.com/img705/1337/layoutxt.jpg](http://img705.yfrog.com/img705/1337/layoutxt.jpg)

I already have this layout created using CSS, but its plagued with issues in IE6 and 7. So I'd like help recreating this layout using **jQuery** (and jQuery Only) for max compatibility. The only difficult part is the **vertically and horizontally resizable (on browser resize as well) content area**.

Edited to add: I need to use jQuery for resizable content area only, I don't want to use the height:100% hacks, they don't work well.

I'd really appreciate any help. Many thanks!

Comment: you could probably use something like http://www.bigbaer.com/css_tutorials/two-column-header-footer.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a table for your layout. You get the resizing of your content area free - no hacks, no javascript, works in all browsers. The purists will be mad at you (and me), but your layout will work and your users will be happy.

Maybe when we get widespread adoption of html 5 and css 3 we will be able to do this nicely with css layouts, but until then...

Comment: I knew it, but wanted to hear from someone else! ;)

Comment: Don't vote him down, it's a valid option! Yes, we all like our divs, but its hard to deny that tables tend to be a lot more stable across the browser spectrum.

Comment: @Toji - thanx - I wish that when someone downvotes a suggestion like this, they would include a working alternate answer.

Comment: Agreed. I think SO even prompts you to leave a comment when you downvote, so it's a wonder that more people don't.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you don't use jQuery for this but keep doing it in CSS (maybe you can post another question asking how to fix it for IE6 and IE7).

Using jQuery for maximum compatibility is a mistake since it requires javascript, and there are people with javascript disabled that would be completely unable to view your website correctly.

Also search engines like google will probably be unable to crawl your website.

Finally, all that javascript and jQuery do is generate html tags and css attributes, so you'll run into the same problems with IE6 and IE7!

Comment: Javascript is not an issue. The only thing I need to use jQuery for is the resizable content area, everything else will be regular html/css ofcourse.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear from your question. But even that part is better done with CSS. As long as the "Aside" div has a fixed or % length then the content area will resize automatically.

Answer (score 1):

HTML defines the semantics. CSS defines the look and layout. And with JS you can do fancy animations and AJAX stuff.

Use everything for what it's made for. JS can also do nothing else then generating HTML and CSS.

Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery will be of no use for your problem, it is a javascript framework (library) to accelerate javascript coding.

You can either do it right with css, or tables, but jquery doesn't have anything to do with layout.